# DOM Snapshot warning when assertions declared in page object is called twice inside same Test in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have declared async function in page object which has few assertions defined to validate for the presence of elements on a page and I have to call this function twice in same test but I am getting warning - "**You passed a DOM snapshot property to the assertion's 't.expect()' method**" even when I am not using await keyword in t.expect().

Please let me know how can I get rid of this warning.

```
fixture('Assertions in Page Object test suite').beforeEach(async t => {
  await t.useRole(login);
});

test('Validate UI for sample page, async t => {
  await pageObject.validateTableUI(t);
  await t.click(pageObject.changeTab); 
  await pageObject.validateTableUI(t);
});
```

The Page object method is :

```
export default class SamplePage {
constructor() {
this.table = Selector('table');
this.tableHeaders = Selector('table thead th);
this.changeTab = Selector('tab);
}

async validateTableUI(t){
await t
      .expect(this.table.visible)
      .ok()
      .expect(this.tableHeaders.visible)
      .ok()
      .expect(this.tableHeaders.nth(1).textContent)
      .contains('Column 1')
      .expect(this.tableHeaders.nth(2).textContent)
      .contains('Column 1');
}
```

Comment: First of all, I'd think about the architecture. Having assertion in Page Object classes will lead to a huge mess later on. Assertions belong to tests, not to POM classes. Just think about when someone looks at your tests... they can't see what youe testing, they actually have to go into this another file (where your POM class is) and have a look there.

Comment: I have a requirement as similar table is displayed in multiple tabs and If I write assertions in Tests only then that will be a duplication so I have created methid in page object class.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no official way to disable these warnings. We are aware of this bug. You can track our progress in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5449).

As a temporary workaround, you can rewrite your `.expect` calls as follows:

```
.expect(
    this.table.visible
)
```